# Is the data-processing inequality still true for higher-order Markov chains?

Tags: references, markov-process, mutual-information

The [data processing inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality) states that if $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ form the first-order Markov chain:

$$
X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow X_n
$$

Then for all $i \leq j \leq k \leq l$:

$$
I(X_i;X_l) \leq I(X_j;X_k)
$$

Where $I(X_i;X_l)$ is the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) between $X_i$ and $X_l$. However, I want to know whether this inequality is still true or not for higher order Markov chains. I will also accept online references that discuss this.

A $k^{th}$ order Markov chain is one in which $X_i$ is conditionally independent of $X_{i-(k+1)},X_{i-(k+2)},...,X_1$ given $X_{i-1},X_{i-2},...,X_{i-k}$. For example, a second-order Markov chain would look like this:

[image]

Where, for example, $X_4$ is conditionally independent of $X_1$ given $X_2$ and $X_3$.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "higher-order" Markov chains?  Many concepts that go by that name are readily reduced to that of your "first-order" chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you mean by 'this inequality'. And, no, I'm not just being difficult.

First (and I think this is what @whuber was being oracular about), if $X_i$ is a second-order Markov chain with state space ${\cal S}$, then the process with state $Y_i=\langle X_i, X_{i-1}\rangle$ at time $i$ is a first-order Markov chain with state space ${\cal S}\times {\cal S}$.  It follows immediately from the result you quote that
$$I(Y_i, Y_l)\leq I(Y_j, Y_k)$$

On the other hand, it does **not** follow that
$$I(X_i, X_l)\leq I(X_j, X_k).$$

Suppose $X$ is actually an interlacing of two first-order Markov chains, so $X_1, X_3, X_5,\ldots$ is first-order Markov and so is $X_2, X_4, X_6,\ldots$.  To take a degenerate case, suppose the odd-times chain has a   very low probability of moving to a new state and the even-times chain has an independent choice of state at each time.

The inequality
$$I(X_i, X_l)\leq I(X_j, X_k).$$
will be true if the indices are all odd or all even, but it will not be true for $i=1$, $l=5$, $j=2$, $k=4$ as, *ex hypothesi*, the information about $X_1$ from $X_5$ is large -- they are very likely to be in the same state -- but the information about $X_2$ from $X_4$ is zero.